# Redirect to previous ROUTE in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

Suppose I'm on this page:

```
http://example.com/users/BECCA/edit/advanced
```

I want to redirect the user to:

`http://example.com/users/BECCA/edit`

How can I do this?

(I'm also familiar with `window.history.back();` but my question is something else!)

Thanks.

Comment: Read up on [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: Have you ever saw this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery

Comment: @sky this-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: @sky did you consider this before?window.location.replace("http://example.com/users/BECCA/edit")

Comment: @Dan Looks like OP is searching for universal solution, like the one [I provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29311050).

Comment: @Ninja Not really a dupe; see the above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Split your current location into an array using delimiter `/`
2. Remove the last object in this array
3. Join the objects into string taking `/` as delimiter

---

```
location.href=location.href.split("/").slice(0,-1).join("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is right but just have one problem, it does't work for http://example.com/
So the better code should be this:

```
var url = location.href.split("/");
if(url.lenght == 3){
//the url is http://example.com/ do what ever you want
}
else{
     location.href=url.slice(0,-1).join("/");
}
```